# Contradiction In Defining Symmetric Difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

One definition of set difference is $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup (B-A).$ If we let $x\in A\Delta B,$ by our definition, we have that $x\in A \space\wedge\space x\notin B$ or $x\in B \space\wedge\space x\notin A$ where the or is inclusive. Since the or is inclusive we have two contradictions, namely, $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$ and $x\in B$ and $x\notin B.$

Is there a way to define the symmetric difference in a way similar to the above, that still uses the inclusive or?

Comment: There's no contradiction at all - the inclusive or **allows for** multiple options to occur, but doesn't **demand that** they occur. In this case it happens that we cannot have both clauses hold simultaneously, so we might as well have used an exclusive or there, but that's not a problem with the inclusive or.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that ($x\in A$ and $x\notin B$) or ($x\notin A$ and $x\in B$) is NOT equivalent, as you seem to imply, to ($x\in A$ and $x\notin A$) and ($x\in B$ and $x\notin B$), what would imply that
$$(A\wedge\neg B)\vee(\neg A\wedge B)\quad\text{and}\quad(A\wedge\neg A)\wedge(B\wedge\neg B),$$
for any formulas $A$ and $B$. You can, indeed, distribute the connectives to "simplify" the expression to
$$\Big((A\wedge \neg B)\vee\neg A\Big)\wedge\Big((A\wedge\neg B)\vee B\Big),$$
and then
$$(A\vee \neg A)\wedge(\neg B\vee \neg A)\wedge (A\vee B)\wedge(\neg B\vee B),$$
equivalent to
$$(A\vee B)\wedge (\neg A\vee \neg B).$$

But this alternative expression of the symmetric difference, as $(A\cup B)\cap(A^{c}\cup B^{c})$, also has no contradictions...

Your problem seems to lie, as Noah Schweber points out in a comment, in the interpretation of the inclusive disjunction: yes, a inclusive disjunction of two true formulas is indeed true, what in informal language is usually referred to as it "allowing" both formulas to be simultaneously true; but this does not mean that two formulas, connected by an inclusive disjunction, CAN be simultaneously true, as in your present case.

($x\in A$ and $x\notin B$) and ($x\notin A$ and $x\in B$) are mutually exclusive: one way you can see that is by noticing the sets they represent, $A\cap B^{c}$ and $A^{c}\cap B$, are disjoint. So there is no contradiction.